# Core Data: error: Exception was caught during Core Data change processing

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, core-data

I have been having this problem now for a few days and it's really frustrating.. I have been reviewing my code over and over again tried different thing and keeps having the same issue.. Which happens only 50% of the times not always. This makes it harder..

**The Problem,**

I am parsing the data from 3 csv files to my Core Data, which 2 of the files parsing always goes well but the middle/second file is where the crash always happens so, this will be address to that file and managedObjectContext class for this file.

**Error Message**

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  
Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  
-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
2014-09-12 11:27:06.115 AppName[210:3907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
```

So, in my **FetchData** class I try to address the problem in different ways.

- First, I changed my .csv file and insert N/A to all the fields/cells that were empty.
- Second, I'm doing a check in my **FetchData** class if this doesn't has any value, save N/A.
- Third, In my view controller where I'm firing the parsing the data, I have now separated three different properties for these 3 entities in my Core Data.

> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContextGI;
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContextVA;

It might be a bit crazy or whatever but I really need to fix this so, trying any possible solution or approach to this it's always good, I think.

ViewController to calling the functions to perform the parsing..

```
//at the beginning of my model
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

-(IBAction)myLoadingTask:(id)sender{

       dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

           NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

           NSString *savedValue = @"";

           if([[userDefaults stringForKey:@"dataFetched"] length] > 0){                            
               savedValue = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"dataFetched"];
           }

           // if the csv files data hasn't been fetch it, then fetch it
           if([savedValue length] == 0){

               FetchData *fd = [[FetchData alloc] initWithManagedContext:self.managedObjectContext];

               // fetching benefits data
               [fd beginParser];

               FetchGIBillData *fdGI = [[FetchGIBillData alloc] initWithManagedContext:self.managedObjectContextGI];

               // fetching gi bill data
               [fdGI beginParser];

               FetchVAPhones *fdVA = [[FetchVAPhones alloc] initWithManagedContext:self.managedObjectContextVA];

               // fetching va phones
               [fdVA beginParser];

               NSString *valueToSave = @"saved";
               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"dataFetched"];
               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

           }

       });
}
```

This is my **Core Data** model functions and so on.. Which I have performed the check if it was empty save **N/A** and so on.. all my properties which are in my entity are **strings**

```
#define GIBILL_FILENAME @"gi_bill_data"

int numOfEntries;
- (id)initWithManagedContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext
{
    self.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
    arrayOfRecords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    numOfEntries=0;
    return self;
}


- (void) beginParser
{
    if (self.managedObjectContext == nil){
        // Error: Must pass in NSManagedObjectContext
        return;
    }

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:GIBILL_FILENAME ofType:@"csv"];
    NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:filePath];
    NSStringEncoding encoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;//NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding;

    CHCSVParser *parser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithInputStream:stream usedEncoding:&encoding delimiter:','];
    parser.delegate = self;

    [parser parse];

    // uncomment to update data x amount of dates
    //[self checkDateForRefreshCSV:parser];

}
```

**** This is where the saving happens!! *****

```
#pragma mark - Data Add
/**
 * addRows
 * @param parser: the CHCSV parser that will parse if required refresh
 * @brief: add the row to ths managedObjectContent DB. All values saved.
 */
- (void) addRows:(CHCSVParser *)parser
{
    int i = -1;
    if ([arrayOfRecords count] == 0) return;
    GIBill *data = [NSEntityDescription
                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"GIBill"
                      inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.facility_code = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.facility_code = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.institution = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.institution = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.city = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.city = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.state = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.state = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.country = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.country = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.bah = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.bah = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.poe = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.poe = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.yr = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.yr = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.gibill = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.gibill = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 0)
        data.cross = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.cross = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.grad_rate = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.grad_rate = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.grad_rate_rank = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.grad_rate_rank = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.default_rate = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.default_rate = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.avg_stu_loan_debt = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.avg_stu_loan_debt = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.avg_stu_loan_debt_rank = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.avg_stu_loan_debt_rank = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.indicator_group = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.indicator_group = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.salary = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.salary = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.zip = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.zip = @"N/A";

    if([[arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:++i] length] > 2)
        data.ope = [arrayOfRecords objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        data.ope = @"N/A";

    NSError *error;

    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];

}
```

Well, I posted the most relevant code that I think of the issue. Please if something else is needed or more details about the problem let me know and I will provide it..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add exception break points and check where it is inserting null.

Comment: You are accessing those contexts across threads using the older Core Data concurrency model, which will cause many problems.

Comment: what do you mean with older core data concurrency model? @quellish

Comment: You are using thread confinement. When you create your NSManagedObjectContexts you are using "init", not "initWithConcurrencyType:" with an argument of either NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType or NSMainQueueConcurrencyType. This means that your NSManagedObjectContext can only be used from the thread where it was created. You are creating the context in one place, then passing it into something that is using a concurrent dispatch queue - which will create as many threads as it needs. The thread confinement concurrency model has been obsolete for some time.

Comment: oh!!!!! Should I create it within my bg thread? @quellish

Comment: You could, you will still have plenty of other problems, like using merge notifications. You should be using nested contexts and private queue confinement for the results you are looking for. This is not only thread safe and performant, but completely removes the need for merge notifications.

Comment: Yah, thanks a lot tho.. But, if I just remove the notifications maybe I could get away with it? @quellish

Comment: No. You will have mysterious, difficult to debug crashes and data corruption.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, the whole problem was creating the `NSManagedObjectContext` and everything in the `Main Thread` and then accessing it or using it in the `Background Thread`.

So, I have just followed [**this post**](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/core-data) and now everything is working perfectly and smooth :)

Thanks a lot for the comments it really put me in the right direction and it was totally what I needed to be able to find the problem..

Thanks!

**In the AppDelegate.h**

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainQueueContext;
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)privateQueueContext;
```

**Then, in my AppDelegate.m**

```
#pragma mark - Singleton Access

+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainQueueContext
{
    return [self mainQueueContext];
}

+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)privateQueueContext
{
    return [self privateQueueContext];
}

#pragma mark - Getters

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainQueueContext
{
    if (!_mainQueueContext) {
        _mainQueueContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        _mainQueueContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    return _mainQueueContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)privateQueueContext
{
    if (!_privateQueueContext) {
        _privateQueueContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        _privateQueueContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    return _privateQueueContext;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(contextDidSavePrivateQueueContext:)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                   object:[self privateQueueContext]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(contextDidSaveMainQueueContext:)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                   object:[self mainQueueContext]];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Notifications

- (void)contextDidSavePrivateQueueContext:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        [self.mainQueueContext performBlock:^{
            [self.mainQueueContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)contextDidSaveMainQueueContext:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        [self.privateQueueContext performBlock:^{
            [self.privateQueueContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

And, finally in my **ViewController** where I am sending the work to the background..

```
// dont forget the macro
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [delegate privateQueueContext];

    // do something in the background with your managedObjectContext!!!!

 });
```

Comment: Why You created public method? `+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)privateQueueContext` as you are using instance method `id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`
    `self.managedObjectContext = [delegate privateQueueContext];`

Comment: how in swift 3 ?

Comment: @Taprolano have you figured it out in swift 3?

Answer (score 32):

The line below saved my day:

```
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

You just have to set the concurrency type as Private. This way it can perform multiple operations on database concurrently on private queue's.

Comment: This could be found in your appDelegate with all other Core Data functions. For Swift it is this line :
     var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType). All credit to this post author. Brilliant catch and day saver.

Answer (score 4):

For people who are doing it in Swift 3:

```
var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 I use this template:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
     */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

lazy var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
}()

lazy var cacheContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    return self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
}()

lazy var updateContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let _updateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    _updateContext.parent = self.viewContext
    return _updateContext
}()
```

and updateContext for update operations.

Comment: Can you explain why privateQueueConcurrencyType is necessary for updateContext, and how you use it?